# Correos php se envían solos... robots o algo así?

Tags: php, email

Tengo el siguiente problema: he hecho un algoritmo que mediante **Ajax** envía variables a un php para que este me envíe un correo electrónico.

Un dato muy importante: en el **script** no permití que se envíen los datos sin que el usuario digite todos los campos y suba dos imágenes.

Todo funciona de maravilla tal y como lo menciono y eso es lo que necesito, el lío es que me llegan correos de vez en cuando sin que nadie haga nada, lo extraño aquí es que me llega el correo sin datos, es decir es como si  sucediera una de dos opciones:

- se burlara lo que hice en el **Js** (cosa que no creo),
- como si se ejecutará el codigo php por si solo, por ejemplo si el correo bajo funcionamiento normal fue enviado por un una persona donde digitó *Pedro* en la casilla nombre, debe llegar el correo con "Nombre: Pedro", es imposible que llegue "Nombre:" ya que como he dicho, en el Javascript no permito que se ejecute envíe si no están todos los datos llenos, es por eso les dejo el código **PHP** en el cual imagino está el problema.

Gracias!

```
<?php

//SE RECIBEN LAS VARIABLES DESDE EL JS PARA LA INFO DEL CORREO

require 'conectar.php';

//Obtener el tipo de archivos subidos
$tipo_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
$tipo_archivo2 = $_FILES['archivo2']['type'];

$nuevo_id=$_POST['nuevo_id'];
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$celular=$_POST['celular'];
$direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
$correo=$_POST['correo'];
$comentarios=$_POST['comentarios'];

//VALIDO SI LOS ARCHIVOS SON IMAGENES y guardo en carpeta ----------------------

if($tipo_archivo == "image/jpeg" && $tipo_archivo2 == "image/jpeg")
{
    $extension=".jpg";
    //recibo el ultimo registro que es el que será para esta cedula

    //creo el directorio con el numero del id actual
    $upload_folder ='../uploads/solicitudes/solicitud'.$nuevo_id;
    mkdir("../uploads/solicitudes/solicitud".$nuevo_id, 0701);

    //nombre del archivo lo pongo como foto1_ + el id
    $nombre_archivo = "foto1_".$nuevo_id.$extension;
    $nombre_archivo2 = "foto2_".$nuevo_id.$extension;

    //$tamano_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];

    $tmp_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $tmp_archivo2 = $_FILES['archivo2']['tmp_name'];

    $archivador = $upload_folder . '/' . $nombre_archivo;
    $archivador2 = $upload_folder . '/' . $nombre_archivo2;

    $ruta_final_foto1="tecflucol.com/sistema/uploads/solicitudes/solicitud"
.$nuevo_id."/foto1_".$nuevo_id.".jpg";


 $ruta_final_foto2="tecflucol.com/sistema/uploads/solicitudes/solicitud"
.$nuevo_id."/foto2_".$nuevo_id.".jpg";

    //variable a retornar
    $return = Array('ok'=>TRUE);

    if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp_archivo, $archivador))
    {
        $return = array('ok' => FALSE, 'msg' => "Ocurrio un error al subir el archivo. No pudo guardarse.", 'status' => 'error');
    }
    if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp_archivo2, $archivador2))
    {
        $return = array('ok' => FALSE, 'msg' => "Ocurrio un error al subir el archivo. No pudo guardarse.", 'status' => 'error');
    }


//hecho todo eso, se envía el correo ---------------------------

$para      = 'tkd.recibidos@gmail.com';
$titulo    = 'Nueva solicitud de revision tecnica '.$nuevo_id;
$mensaje   = 'Se ha recibido una nueva solicitud de instalacion de gas, 
numero : '.$nuevo_id."\r\n"."\r\n".

'DATOS DEL SOLICITANTE:'."\r\n".
'Nombre: '.$nombre."\r\n".
'Celular: '.$celular."\r\n".
'Direccion: '.$direccion."\r\n".
'Comentarios: '.$comentarios."\r\n".
'e-mail: '.$correo."\r\n"."\r\n".

'DATOS ADJUNTOS:'."\r\n"."\r\n".
'Foto1: '.$ruta_final_foto1."\r\n"."\r\n".
'Foto2: '.$ruta_final_foto2."\r\n"."\r\n";

$cabeceras = 'From: solicitudgas@tecflucol.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$correo . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);

echo json_encode($return);
}

else{
//aquí haré algo mas adelante si no es una imagen lo que se adjuntó, en este momento no es relevante
}
?>
```

Comment: Pues me parece más probable lo primero: desactivar Javascript en un navegador es algo inmediato, cualquier seguridad **debe** implementarse **siempre** en el lado del servidor. Las comprobaciones en el lado del cliente son más cosméticas que otra cosa

Answer (score 0):

**Aqui tienes, espero te sirva**

```
<?php

//SE RECIBEN LAS VARIABLES DESDE EL JS PARA LA INFO DEL CORREO

require 'conectar.php';

//Obtener el tipo de archivos subidos
$tipo_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
$tipo_archivo2 = $_FILES['archivo2']['type'];

$nuevo_id=$_POST['nuevo_id'];
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$celular=$_POST['celular'];
$direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
$correo=$_POST['correo'];
$comentarios=$_POST['comentarios'];

//VALIDO SI LOS ARCHIVOS SON IMAGENES y guardo en carpeta ----------------------

if($tipo_archivo == "image/jpeg" && $tipo_archivo2 == "image/jpeg")
{
    $extension=".jpg";
    //recibo el ultimo registro que es el que será para esta cedula

    //creo el directorio con el numero del id actual
    $upload_folder ='../uploads/solicitudes/solicitud'.$nuevo_id;
    mkdir("../uploads/solicitudes/solicitud".$nuevo_id, 0701);

    //nombre del archivo lo pongo como foto1_ + el id
    $nombre_archivo = "foto1_".$nuevo_id.$extension;
    $nombre_archivo2 = "foto2_".$nuevo_id.$extension;

    //$tamano_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];

    $tmp_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $tmp_archivo2 = $_FILES['archivo2']['tmp_name'];

    $archivador = $upload_folder . '/' . $nombre_archivo;
    $archivador2 = $upload_folder . '/' . $nombre_archivo2;

    $ruta_final_foto1="tecflucol.com/sistema/uploads/solicitudes/solicitud"
.$nuevo_id."/foto1_".$nuevo_id.".jpg";


 $ruta_final_foto2="tecflucol.com/sistema/uploads/solicitudes/solicitud"
.$nuevo_id."/foto2_".$nuevo_id.".jpg";

    //variable a retornar
    $return = Array('ok'=>TRUE);

    if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp_archivo, $archivador))
    {
        $return = array('ok' => FALSE, 'msg' => "Ocurrio un error al subir el archivo. No pudo guardarse.", 'status' => 'error');
    }
    if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp_archivo2, $archivador2))
    {
        $return = array('ok' => FALSE, 'msg' => "Ocurrio un error al subir el archivo. No pudo guardarse.", 'status' => 'error');
    }


//hecho todo eso, se envía el correo ---------------------------

//creamos una verificación que contenga estos campos, nuevo id, nombre, celular,dirección y correo, de no ser asi, no se mandará nada.
if (!empty(@$_POST['nuevo_id'] && @$_POST['nombre'] && @$_POST['celular'] && @$_POST['direccion'] && @$_POST['correo'])){

$para      = 'tkd.recibidos@gmail.com';
$titulo    = 'Nueva solicitud de revision tecnica '.$nuevo_id;
$mensaje   = 'Se ha recibido una nueva solicitud de instalacion de gas, 
numero : '.$nuevo_id."\r\n"."\r\n".

'DATOS DEL SOLICITANTE:'."\r\n".
'Nombre: '.$nombre."\r\n".
'Celular: '.$celular."\r\n".
'Direccion: '.$direccion."\r\n".
'Comentarios: '.$comentarios."\r\n".
'e-mail: '.$correo."\r\n"."\r\n".

'DATOS ADJUNTOS:'."\r\n"."\r\n".
'Foto1: '.$ruta_final_foto1."\r\n"."\r\n".
'Foto2: '.$ruta_final_foto2."\r\n"."\r\n";

$cabeceras = 'From: solicitudgas@tecflucol.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$correo . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);

echo json_encode($return);
}

else{
//aquí haré algo mas adelante si no es una imagen lo que se adjuntó, en este momento no es relevante
}

//cerramos llave de verificación
}
?>
```

Comment: Gracias! eso había pensado pero no sabia exactamente como escribirlo, veré si funciona... la duda que me queda es... pareciera que se ejecutará todo el archivo completo php... de ser así lo tuyo serviría ya que tendria que meterse en el if... en caso de que no se ejecute todo desde el principio si no simplemente la parte de enviar el email, pues no serviría... es posible que se ejecute solo esa parte?